# Is there a way to get only the found document as the result of findAndModify without the wrapping info

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, findandmodify

I have a `findAndModify` MongoDb request. The mongo server wraps the document in:

```
{
    value: { ... },
    lastErrorObject: { updatedExisting: true, n: 1 },
    ok: 1
}
```

is there a way to only get the object from the `value` key?

```
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way you get that kind of response is by directly running the [`findAndModify`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/) database command form, for example:

```js
db.runCommand({
    "findAndModify": "newdata", 
    "query": { "a": 1 }, 
    "update": { "$set": { "b": 2 } }, 
    "new": true, 
    "upsert": true 
})
```

In the MongoDB shell and all driver implementations these methods are always wrapped with a [collection method](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) so that just the document which is modified ( or the original if you ask for that ) is returned in the response. In the shell the wrapping code looks like this:

```js
function (args){
    var cmd = { findandmodify: this.getName() };
    for (var key in args){
    cmd[key] = args[key];
    }

    var ret = this._db.runCommand( cmd );
    if ( ! ret.ok ){
        if (ret.errmsg == "No matching object found"){
        return null;
        }
        throw "findAndModifyFailed failed: " + tojson( ret );
    }
    return ret.value;
}
```

So when you in fact just invoke that method from the collection object then you just get the document in response:

```js
db.newdata.findAndModify({ 
    "query": { "a": 1 }, 
    "update": { "$set": { "b": 2 } }, 
    "new": true, 
    "upsert": true 
})

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5445af1ac745bf5663de72dd"), "a" : 1, "b" : 2 }
```

This is common to all drivers, some of which show alternate names to "findAndModify" such as "findAndUpdate" and specifically separate the "remove" and "update" functionality for each. Consult your language driver documentation for more details on other implementations, but they basically work in the same way.